# SQL Case select

Tags: sql, sql-server

maybe someone can help me

i have an SQL datebase that is used for logging employees leave. we have some many different shifts, that on our employees table we have 7 fields that represent the days they work. these are a bit data type, 1 for working that day, and 0 for not working.

a second table has all the employees leave. containing employee id, leave date and reason.

i can easily query the employees table and get how many people are to work on any given day of the week, and i can easily query the leave table to see how many people are off on a given date.

what i looking to do is based on the day of the week in the leave table, count how many people are supposed to be in on that day.

the code im trying to make work is

```
select TBL_Leave.Leave_Date AS 'Date',
    datepart(weekday,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) - 1 AS 'Day Of Week',
    count(TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) AS 'Total Off',

    case
        when datepart(weekday,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) - 1 = 5 then select SUM(convert(int,Mon)) from TBL_Employees)
        else 'Flase'
    end

from TBL_Leave

where Leave_Date between '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'

group by TBL_Leave.Leave_Date
```

but sure enough, it dont work.

im trying to count the number of people working from one table based the the day of the week from a field in another.

any help anyone can give will be great

cheers
Paul

---

i have this query to get how many people are off on any date

```
select TBL_Leave.Leave_Date AS 'Date',
    datepart(weekday,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) - 1 AS 'Day Of Week',
    count(TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) AS 'Total Off'

from TBL_Leave

where Leave_Date between '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'

group by TBL_Leave.Leave_Date
```

and this to see how many people are in on any day

```
select SUM(convert(int,Mon)) as 'Monday',
       SUM(convert(int,Tue)) AS 'Tuesday',
       SUM(convert(int,Wed)) AS 'Wednesday',
       SUM(convert(int,Thu)) AS 'Thursday',
       SUM(convert(int,Fri)) AS 'Friday',
       SUM(convert(int,Sat)) AS 'Saturday',
       SUM(convert(int,Sun)) AS 'Sunday'

from TBL_Employees

where planned = 1
```

Comment: We could throw this together easily, but we don't know how your tables are structured and nothing in your code even looks at the list of employees, gief moar data!

Comment: Not an answer, but what's the point of "datepart(weekday,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) - 1 = 5" why not "datepart(weekday,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) =4"?

Comment: @jv, the table of employees has 7 fields for mon to sun for each employee, what i want to do is, if the an entry in the leave table is a monday, count how many people are planned to work on a monday. the code that i have posted is a bit messed up anyway, that was after trying different things

Comment: 7 fields, mon to sun, and this doesn't leave any space for info on the employee... I assume theres another field ID or something?

Comment: oh yeah, there is first name, last name, id, clock number, skill1, skill2, skill3, include in plan, but they are not relevent for the query that im trying to run. when someone is planned for any given day, their mon, tue, wed.... field will be 1 for when they are working that day, and 0 for when they are off. i can count the amount of people off on any given date, but if that date is a monday, i want to count or sum i suppose, how many people in the employee table have a 1 on the monday field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you should set a view in place as a helper for queries like these:

```
create view V_EmployeeWorkingDays as
select EmployeeID,
       case ShortDayName
       when 'Mon' then 1 when 'Tue' then 2 when 'Wed' then 3
       when 'Thu' then 4 when 'Fri' then 5 when 'Sat' then 6
       when 'Sun' then 7 end as weekday,
       IsWorking
from   TBL_Employees
unpivot (IstWorking for ShortDayName in (Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun)) p;
```

Secondly you need the calendar dates within your range. You could use a function like this:

```
create function F_DateValues(@FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime)
returns table as
return (
    select  dateadd(day,Nr-1,@FromDate) as Date
    from    (select  row_number() over (rand()) as Nr
            from    (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) a
            cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) b 
            cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) c
            cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1)) c) n
    where   Nr > datediff(day,@FromDate,@ToDate)
);
```

Now you can put this alltogether:

```
select  d.Date,
        isnull(w.CountWorkingPlanned,0)-isnull(l.CountLeaves,0) as CountWorking
from    F_DateValue('20101118','20101128') d
left join (select LeaveDate, count(*) as CountLeaves
           from TBL_LeaveDate group by LeaveDate) l
    on  l.LeaveDate = d.Date
left join (select weekday, count(*) as CountWorkingPlanned
           from V_EmployeeWorkingDays where IsWorking=1 group by weekday) w
    on w.weekday = datepart(weekday,d.Date);
```

This should be working (not tested - so please don't kill me for typos ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

You should redesign the table layout. As you have a field for each weekday, that means that you have data in the field names. Data belongs inside the table, so you should put that data as rows in a separate table.

Then it's easy to get the data. Example:

```
select count(*)
from Employees e
left join Leave l on l.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId and LeaveDate = @Today
left join Workdays w on w.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId and w.WeekDay = datepart(weekday, @Today)
where l..EmployeeId is null and w.EmployeeId is null
```

Comment: just to confirm, move the fields for each day of the week into its own table plus an id to link back to the employees table. so each employee in the employee table will have a link to the workday table?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the workdays table would have fields for employee id and weekday. Then you can choose to have a bit field for working/free, or let the existance of a record mean working. The crucial thing is that a user would have a row in the table for each weekday instead of one row with seven fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(id) FROM employee WHERE monday = true
```

Seems easy enough unless I still don't get what you need...

Comment: that part is easy, i can count from the employee table, and i can count from the leave table, but i want to join them somehow, so that for each entry in the leave field, i can see how many people are planned to be in on that day

Comment: i have added some more to my question, i can see what i want in my head, but dont know how to get it down on paper to ask the question

Comment: so you can see unplanned leaves? Sorry, you will need to give us full tables and an instruction on the final values that need to be returned.

Comment: its more to allow for planning for extra staff from overtime and temps. we know how many people it takes to run a shift. what i want to do, is see a difference between planned staff, people on leave and required staff. in my results tab i want to see, date | people off | amount of people that are normally supposed to work on that day based on the day of the week.

Comment: These are 3 different queries, and none of them have to be joined together.

Comment: do you know if you can do a select statement with in a case select

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that might work for you.

The query uses derived queries to get the leave and work counts.  I included an UNPIVOT operation on the TBL_Employee data to make it easier to get the employee data.  You can avoid this with design changes that have been suggested.

```
SELECT Leave.Leave_Date, WorkCount, LeaveCount,
       WorkCount-LeaveCount AS CountDifference
FROM
    (
    -- Get Leave counts by date
    SELECT Leave_Date, UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(dw, Leave_Date), 3)) AS WorkDay,
        COUNT(*) as LeaveCount
    FROM TBL_Leave
    WHERE Leave_Date between '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'
    GROUP BY Leave_Date, UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(dw, Leave_Date), 3))
    ) AS Leave
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    -- Get Work counts by day of week
    SELECT WorkDay, COUNT(*) WorkCount
    FROM 
       (
       SELECT EmpID, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
       FROM TBL_Employees
       ) p
        UNPIVOT
           (IsWorking FOR WorkDay IN 
              (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
           )AS unpvt
    WHERE unpvt.IsWorking = 1
    GROUP BY WorkDay
    ) AS Work ON Leave.WorkDay = Work.WorkDay  -- Join on day of week
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyones help on this, i have picked up a few tips. i managed to get this sorted last night and when i look at it, i think i made it sound more complicated than it is. here is what i came up with.

```
create table TEMP_planned (id int null, mon int null, tue int null, wed int null, thur             int null, fri int null, sat int null, sun int null)

insert into TEMP_planned (id, mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun) 

values(1,
(select SUM(convert(int,Mon)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Tue)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Wed)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Thu)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Fri)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Sat)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1),
(select SUM(convert(int,Sun)) from TBL_Employees where Planned = 1))


select  TBL_Leave.Leave_Date,   
    'Planned' = case DATEPART(dw,TBL_Leave.Leave_Date) - 1
        when 1 then (select mon from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 2 then (select tue from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 3 then (select wed from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 4 then (select thur from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 5 then (select fri from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 6 then (select sat from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
        when 7 then (select sun from TEMP_Planned where ID = 1)
    end,
    COUNT(tbl_leave.Leave_Date) as 'Total Staff Off'    

from TBL_Leave

group by    TBL_Leave.Leave_Date

drop table temp_planned
```